What's a suitable usage example (at most 4 chars) for the character 靖?
I'm making (simplified) character study materials, where I list characters with an example where they're likely encountered.  I use it for character learning and handwriting practice like this:



I reached the character 靖 (it's listed in 通用规范汉字表 and 现代汉语常用字表; it's character 2568 in Heisig and Richardson's Remembering Simplified Hanzi).
I want to add a 词语 for the character 靖 (max 4 chars).
My code found: 靖国神社.  I'd prefer to avoid this term if possible, as it seems controversial.  Other words like 安靖 宁靖 seem to be 安静 宁静 in disguise.  It seems 平靖 might be the best choice.  I'm unsure what's the best choice here.
Question: What's a suitable usage example (at most 4 chars) for the character 靖?

“靖康之難” https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=96249&q=1&word=%E9%9D%96 , or 靖難 https://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/dictView.jsp?ID=96243&word=%E9%9D%96&q=2

Check out this page.

靖，立竫也。——《说文》
靖，stand easy yeah ——《Shuowen》
(竫: 安静：“竫立安坐而至者，因其械也。”)
如:
靖密(安静致密);(peaceful, still)
靖冥(宁静幽深);(tranquil, serene)
靖默(沉静缄默);(peaceful, quiet)
靖重(安祥凝重);(serene, dignified)
靖晏(平静安逸,太平无事);(tranquil, at ease, peace and security, no problems)
靖遏(安定);(stable)

The most prominent example of 靖 in Chinese literature is 靖康之难 (The Disaster of Jingkang years) when two Chinese emperors were captured by the enemy.
You can just remember 靖康 /Jing kang/ (1125-1127)
Otherwise, you can search for 靖:

靖: 平定、使安定 (put down, make stable)


靖乱 (put down upheaval)

靖难 (relieve disaster)



靖 -

靖边(安定边境)

靖匡(安定、挽救、扶助)

靖兵(息兵，休战)

嘉靖(朝代 - 明朝嘉靖帝朱厚熜的年号)

李靖(号托塔天王，中国古代神话传说的军神)


又, 古同“静” -

靖密(安静致密);靖冥(宁静幽深);靖默(沉静缄默);靖重(安祥凝重)

